# Weight Decay and input normalization

Tags: tensorflow, normalization

I'm new to tensorflow and find that the sample CNN programs are using weight decay to avoid huge weight while they do not always normalize the input in the first place.

Does the weight decay serve the same purpose as the input normalization?

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

**Weight decay** is a type of regularisation used to control overfitting of the model. Weight decay is more commonly known as L2 Normalisation. Weight decay is used more in common in shallow learning algorithms like linear regression, logistic regression etc. In deep learning (ex: which uses CNN), weight decay is not so common. In fact other regularisation methods like dropout is used.

**Input normalisation** on the other hand refers to zero centering your input data and limiting the range of the input data. This procedure helps in quick convergence of the data.

There is no general fixed rule on how this two concepts has to be applied. Hence, you may have seen some variations of this two concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Weight decay is a regularization technique such as L2 regularization that result in gradient descent shrinking the weights on every iteration